# Is there any method in fasttext that takes two words as inputs and returns their similarity

Tags: nlp, word2vec, fasttext

I have followed [this](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/unsupervised-tutorial.html) documentation to get fasttext running, fairly straightforward. Commands such as  `$ ./fasttext nn result/fil9.bin` can be used to find nearest neighbour of a word. However, is there any such simple command in fasttext that takes two words such as "Vehicle" and "Car" as input and returns their (cosine) similarity i.e. a number like 0.777.

Answer (score 1):

At present time, it's not part of the API. You can use gensim, or write your own distance metric calculation.